# How to pass an element ID into parameters of a function? HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
function ValueLimit(min, max, mode){

        var v;
        if(mode === "h"){
            v = document.getElementById("weight_imp").value;

            if(v < min){document.getElementById("weight_imp").value = min;}
            if(v > max){document.getElementById("weight_imp").value = max;}
        }

        if(mode === "w"){
            v = document.getElementById("weight_imp").value;

            if(v < min){document.getElementById("weight_imp").value = min;}
            if(v > max){document.getElementById("weight_imp").value = max;}
        }
    }
```

I need to replace mode with an ID of an input element
This should in turn make the code significantly smaller
I cannot seem to find a way to pass it through
It should be able to target any element on the page

Comment: I don't understand what your asking. Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you pass your function an actual element instead of a selector (which has the added benefit of not requiring every `input` to have an `id`). You can also make the implementation much shorter using `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

```js
function clampValue (e, min, max){
  e.value = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, +e.value))
}

var input = document.getElementById('weight_imp')

function exampleUsage () {
  clampValue(input, 0, 100)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="weight_imp">
<button onclick="exampleUsage()">Clamp [0, 100]</button>
```